# Where did my comment go?

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178787) has some controversy over whether it belongs on P.SE, so I posted a comment yesterday pointing out that the FAQ says "freelancing and business concerns" are on-topic. Someone upvoted that comment.

Today, the comment is gone. In fact, there is at least one other comment I distinctly remember that is also no longer there. These comments could not have reasonably been considered offensive. Where did they go?

Comment: Being offensive or rude is _not_ the only reason a comment might be deleted, see: [When shouldn't I comment?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment). The comment discussion in your question went on for a while, and some of the comments outlived their purpose (yours wasn't the only one that was deleted).

Comment: OK, but the community is trying to decide whether the question is on-topic or not. While I understand the principle of not leaving tons of meta-comments on an active question, since this question is currently closed meta comments have a valid and active purpose, and arbitrarily removing them can bias the community.

Comment: @kojiro Discussions of the suitableness or topicality of a question should be brought to Meta. Comments should be used to ask clarifying questions or point out problems with either questions or answers. Comments are not for extended discussion (in fact, too many comments on a question triggers a moderator flag to clean up any comments that have outlived their usefulness or to address an extended conversation).

Comment: Sure, how about we take the discussion on Meta? It's a much better venue for such discussions...

Comment: @YannisRizos [you're right](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/5327) of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cleaned up comments that were wrong or chatty on that question.

Although freelancing and business concerns are indeed on-topic, there's also a section in the FAQ that says:

> Please make sure your question uniquely applies to programmers in general:
>
> [image: Programmers Audience]

The concept of NDAs apply equally to other professions, making your comment incorrect.

Comments on Stack Exchange sites are second-class citizens. Unless you are rude or offensive, having a comment deleted is nothing to worry about.

Also, if there's a concern about a question, the best place to take it isn't the comments, but to Meta or [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).